# Including Spring @Retryable without main or service class

Tags: spring, api, spring-retry

I have an api that does not have main method in it, It is just set of classes for calling database procedures. None of the classes has Service annotation in them.
I am including this api in another spring boot application.
When I annotate any method as @Retryable in external api and call from Spring boot application it does not provide retry.

Can you please help on this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have @Configuration annotated class in your external api?

Can you check , whether you **enabled** retry using **@EnableRetry?**
This should be declared on any @Configuration class in your external api.

> org.springframework.retry.annotation
>
> **Annotation Type EnableRetry**
>
> Global enabler for @Retryable annotations in Spring beans. If this is
> declared on **any @Configuration in the context** then beans that have
> retryable methods will be proxied and the retry handled according to
> the metadata in the annotations.